# Cannot import RDF url content into GraphDB

Tags: rdf, rdflib, graphdb, rdf4j, openrdf

I have on a Web server an URL which serializes a RDF triplestore with Python module rdflib. I want to import this content into GraphDB.

The rdflib.serialize output format is "xml". The MIME type of the HTTP header is "xml/rdf" but the result is the same with the MIME type "text/rdf".

When the content is saved to a text file ending with ".rdf" extension, GraphDB can import this file without problem, and the repository content is OK.

The URL can be imported in the software "Protégé" which is a semantic web tool and RDF editor.

But, when importing the same URL into GraphDB, I get the error message:

```
"Could not find RDF format for URL: (... my url ... )"
```

I tried several things, without success:

- I checked that GraphDB expects the same data format from URL and text files.
- In GraphDB "Import advanced settings", I unchecked the flags "Verify URI" and "should stop on error".
- I tried with Apache web server and a simple Python class BaseHTTPServer.

I suspect that this error message comes from the [openrdf library](https://github.com/ansell/openrdf-sesame/blob/master/core/repository/api/src/main/java/org/openrdf/repository/util/RDFLoader.java) which outputs this message when it cannot determine the content type based on the file extension of the URL or the content type in the HTTP response header, but I think I set it correctly.

***What is the problem?***

Comment: Neither "xml/rdf" nor "text/rdf" are correct MIME-types. It should be "application/xml+rdf" or possibly "application/xml" or "text/xml".

Comment: Sorry, that should be "application/rdf+xml", not "application/xml+rdf". See http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/eclipse/rdf4j/rio/RDFFormat.html#RDFXML

Comment: 'application/xml' worked perfectly. "application/xml+rdf" did not work. Many thanks.

Comment: as an aside: unless you are using a _very_ old version of GraphDB, it's more likely to be using the rdf4j libraries instead of openrdf sesame. Sesame was discontinued a few years ago, Eclipse rdf4j is the successor project.

Answer (score 3):

(converting comment to answer)

The problem is that "xml/rdf" and "text/rdf" are not known MIME-types for the RDF/XML file format.

The correct MIME-type to use is "application/rdf+xml". Optionally as a fallback "application/xml" or "text/xml" may also work. See the [rdf4j javadoc for RDF formats](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/eclipse/rdf4j/rio/RDFFormat.html#RDFXML) for details.